# Evaluating a multivariable function on an array with python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that python allows a fast evalutation of a real-valued, one variable function `f(x)` on a numpy array `xarr = np.array([x0,x1,...xN])`:

`f(xarr) = np.array([f(x0), f(x1), ..., f(xN)])`

However, this doesn't seem to work syntax-wise for a multivariable function. Say I have a real-valued function `f(x,y)`, where x and y are two real numbers. Is there a correct syntax to evaluate the function on, say, `[(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]`, avoiding a loop (which is always slow on python...)?

Edit: below are the functions involved:

The 5-variable function I refer to is:

```
def chisqr(BigOmega, inc, taustar, Q0, U0):
      QU = QandU(nusdata, BigOmega, inc, taustar, Q0, U0)
      Q = QU[:,0]
      U = QU[:,1]
      return 1./(2.*N) * (np.sum(((Q - Qs)/errQs)**2.) + np.sum(((U - Us)/errUs)**2.))
```

where `nusdata, Qs,` and `Us` are arrays defined before calling the function. The function calls the following function:

```
def QandU(nu, BigOmega, inc, taustar, Q0, U0):
      lambdalong = nu+omega-np.pi/2.
      tau3 = taustar * ((1+ecc*np.cos(nu))/(1-ecc**2.))**gamma
      delQ = -tau3 * (1+np.cos(inc)*np.cos(inc))*(np.cos(2.*lambdalong) np.sin(inc)*np.sin(inc))
      delU = -2*tau3*np.cos(inc)*np.sin(2*lambdalong)
      Q = Q0 + delQ*np.cos(BigOmega) - delU * np.sin(BigOmega)
      U = U0 + delQ*np.sin(BigOmega) + delU * np.cos(BigOmega)
      bounds = (inc < 0) or (inc > np.pi/2.) or (BigOmega < -2*np.pi) or (BigOmega > 2*np.pi) or (taustar < 0.) or (taustar > 1.)
      if bounds:
            Q = 10E10
            U = 10E10
      #return U
      return np.column_stack((Q,U))
```

All variables which aren't the function's arguments are defined outside the function.

Comment: Can you give the function you want to evaluate?

Comment: You just need to define your function to take one argument (the tuple or pair) but operate on the elements of the tuple.  Something as simple as `f = lambda x: x[0]*x[1]` can work.

Comment: There are often ways to do this, but there's no generalized answer.  Some functions are easy and some are impossible.  You need to show the actual function.

Comment: Tnx for the comments. syntonym: The function I want to evaluate is a complicated function involving trigonometric functions etc, and it's a function of 5 parameters (it's actually a chi2). It's not defined using lambdas but with a simple def .... return ... syntax. I could write it down, but I can't imagine why this should help...

Comment: Hey, I meant no offence - I'll edit my reply to include the function...

Comment: Can you explain the connection between the functions you're rtrying to call and your question? Which function do you want to call over what array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple example:

```
def add_squares(x, y):
    return x*x + y*y

xs = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
ys = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

res = add_squares(x, y)
```

```
np.array([0, 1, 2, 1])
```

Your statement that `f(xarr) = np.array([f(x0), f(x1), ..., f(xN)])` is not in general true. This entirely depends on the definition of `f`. If f consists only of arithmetic operations, then it is true, but in general, it is not.

---

Your `QandU` function should almost work as intended:

```
def QandU(nu, BigOmega, inc, taustar, Q0, U0):
    # left unchanged
    lambdalong = nu+omega-np.pi/2.
    tau3 = taustar * ((1+ecc*np.cos(nu))/(1-ecc**2.))**gamma
    delQ = -tau3 * (1+np.cos(inc)*np.cos(inc))*(np.cos(2.*lambdalong) np.sin(inc)*np.sin(inc))
    delU = -2*tau3*np.cos(inc)*np.sin(2*lambdalong)
    Q = Q0 + delQ*np.cos(BigOmega) - delU * np.sin(BigOmega)
    U = U0 + delQ*np.sin(BigOmega) + delU * np.cos(BigOmega)

    # or doesn't vectorize, use bitwise or
    bounds = (inc < 0) | (inc > np.pi/2.) | (BigOmega < -2*np.pi) | (BigOmega > 2*np.pi) | (taustar < 0.) | (taustar > 1.)

    # if statements also don't vectorize
    Q[bounds] = 10E10
    U[bounds] = 10E10

    # stacking is more trouble that it's worth
    return Q, U
```

Your `chisqr` function will probably need an `axis=` argument passed to `sum`, depending exactly which dimensions you want to sum over.